# get KofaxValues besides IndexFields and BatchFields

Tags: c#, kofax

I want to access the KofaxValues. Currently I know how to work with IndexFields and BatchFields but I don't know how to access these KofaxValues within my setup script.

The `ReleaseSetup` object contains IndexFields and BatchFields. When launching the Text Exporter in the Kofax Capture Administration module you can map the Kofax Values to your own values.

*(the language is german)*

[image]

It is possible to loop through the fields

```
            foreach (IndexField field in releaseSetupData.IndexFields)
            {
                // do something with the field
            }

            foreach (BatchField field in releaseSetupData.BatchFields)
            {
                // do something with the field
            }
```

but where can I find the Kofax Values? I use the **Kofax Capture Export Type Library API Reference Guide**

---

**Edit:**

When it comes to the release I know I could do something like

```
        foreach (Value val in releaseData.Values)
        {
            bool isKofaxValue = val.SourceType == KfxLinkSourceType.KFX_REL_VARIABLE;

            if (val.TableName.IsEmpty())
            {
                string sourceName = val.SourceName;
                string sourceValue = val.Value;

                // ...
            }
        }
```

but I don't know how to access them from the setup object.

A pseudo code example would be

```
        foreach (KofaxValue val in releaseSetupData.KofaxValues)
        {
            releaseSetupData.Links.Add(val.Name, KfxLinkSourceType.KFX_REL_VARIABLE, val.Name);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there. They can be found in the `BatchVariableNames` collection on the `SetupData` object. The following sample adds all of them to the `Links` collection, i.e. exposing them for release:

```
foreach (var item in setupData.BatchVariableNames)
{
    setupData.Links.Add(item, KfxLinkSourceType.KFX_REL_VARIABLE, item);
}
```